# Z3 disable assertion simplification for proofs

Tags: z3, key-formal-verification

Is there any way to disable simplification/rewriting of assertions in Z3 (version 4.8.8)?

I am currently working on proof replay of Z3 proofs within KeY (https://www.key-project.org). However, to be able to replay Z3's "asserted" rule, I need the exact assertion as specified in the SMT-LIB input to Z3, not a simplified version of it.

As an extreme example of what could happen, consider this SMT-LIB input:

```
(set-option :produce-proofs true)

(assert
  (not
    (forall ((y Int))
      (exists ((x Int))
        (= x (+ y 1))
      )
    )
  )
)
(check-sat)
(get-proof)
```

Running Z3 4.8.8 leads to the following output:

```
unsat
((proof
(asserted false)))
```

Obviously, the assertion has been simplified, which makes the proof not really helpful.
Is there any way to completely disable this simplification (and thus get a "real" proof from Z3, which I can replay in our tool)?

Answer (score 0):

You might be better served if you use a more recent version of z3. For instance, given your example, a recently compiled-from-github-master version produces:

```
((proof
(let (($x88 (not true)))
 (let (($x48 (forall ((y Int) )(! (exists ((x Int) )(! (= x (+ 1 y)) :qid k!8))
  :qid k!9))
 ))
 (let (($x54 (not $x48)))
 (let ((@x36 (rewrite (= $x54 $x54))))
 (let (($x30 (forall ((y Int) )(! (exists ((x Int) )(! (= x (+ y 1)) :qid k!8))
  :qid k!9))
 ))
 (let (($x31 (not $x30)))
 (let ((@x32 (asserted $x31)))
 (let ((@x45 (mp (mp (mp @x32 (rewrite (= $x31 $x54)) $x54) @x36 $x54) @x36 $x54)))
 (let ((@x53 (mp (mp (mp @x45 @x36 $x54) @x36 $x54) (rewrite (= $x54 $x88)) $x88)))
 (mp @x53 (rewrite (= $x88 false)) false))))))))))))
```

The format remains undocumented, and in general it will be really hard for z3 to produce granular proofs in the presence of quantifiers. A direct quote from: [https://theory.stanford.edu/~nikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-proofs](https://theory.stanford.edu/%7Enikolaj/programmingz3.html#sec-proofs) says:

> The granularity of proof objects is on a best-effort basis. Proofs for
> the SMT Core, are relatively fined-grained, while proofs for
> procedures that perform quantifier elimination, for instance QSAT
> described in Section 6.4, are exposed as big opaque steps.

Comment: Thank you for the hint about the version, I did not realize there already was a newer one. With version 4.8.9, as you stated, the assertion is not simplified any more. However, does this version of Z3 guarantee that no simplification occurs, i.e. that the formula inside the `asserted` rule is exactly the same as stated in the input file (maybe apart from sharing via `let` and annotations as in this example)?

Comment: No. I don't think there are any guarantees as to what sort of simplifications will happen. If you run `z3 -p | grep simplify` you'll see a bunch of simplification related settings. (And also look for the output of `z3 -p` in general.) Tweaking these might get you something consistent, but I wouldn't rely on any particular behavior when it comes to the generated proof objects.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Apparently this is bad news for proof replay. I hope that it is then possible to assign names to assertions to identify them reliably in replay of the `asserted` rule (related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418322/naming-assertions-in-z3-proofs).