# Naming assertions in Z3 proofs

Tags: z3

Is it possible to get assertion names inside Z3 (version 4.8.9) proofs?
As a minimal example:

```
(set-option :produce-proofs true)
(assert (! false :named name))
(check-sat)
(get-proof)
```

I would like to have the following output:

```
unsat
((proof (asserted name)))
```

However, this is the actual output:

```
unsat
((proof (asserted false)))
```

Is it possible to have the proof refering to the assertion names instead of the actual formula?

Via experimenting, I found out that it is possible to add `(set-option :unsat-core true)`.
However, this makes the proof more complicated. With the option set, the output is:

```
unsat
((proof
(let (($x27 (not name)))
(let ((@x30 (mp (asserted (=> name false)) (rewrite (= (=> name false) $x27)) $x27)))
(unit-resolution @x30 (asserted name) false)))))
```

Also I am not sure if enabling proof and unsat-core generation simultaneously is allowed, in https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/189#issuecomment-129786093 NikolajBjorner states:

> Z3 doesn't really support simultaneous proof and core generation, ...

Answer (score 0):

This is extremely unlikely. Names are pretty much only used in unsat-core generation. Proof objects in z3 remain more or less a black-box. However, if you restrict yourself to only bit-vectors, it might work better. See: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-25379-9_15

This paper is also quite relevant in this context: [http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~ajreynol/lpar15.pdf](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Eajreynol/lpar15.pdf). In short, BV-solvers usually reduce the problem to propositional reasoning, and thus resolution-style proofs that can be easily checked by external tools are much easier to construct. But for other logics, and especially when quantifiers are involved, the proof steps can be rather opaque and replay will be much more difficult.

Comment: The "more complicated" proof literally contains just the name binding; it introduces a Boolean variable called "name" and makes that imply the constraint. Note that unsat cores are not necessarily always replayable in practice, e.g. when e-matching performance depends on subterms in assertions that do not affect satisfiability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that the proofs are not documented very well. That is why I hoped for some definite answer. Restricting myselft to bit-vectors is not possible for my project: I try to outsource proof search from the KeY tool to Z3, afterwards applying some replay technique to get a complete proof inside our tool. However, proof granularity is not the problem: During replay of a Z3 proof, for coarse (but local) steps like `rewrite` or `th-lemma` I can search for a proof in KeY directly. The problem is to replay the `asserted` rule, since the assertion may be rewritten.